# Timestamp in 5 days from today in at 0 o'clock

Tags: php, wordpress, date, timestamp, strtotime

I am looking for a simple way to get a timestamp relative to today, but at a specific time.

Example:
Right now is 07-01-2020 10:00 a.m.
Result: Time stamp of 06.07.2020 0 o'clock

Only that the values of today are varbiale. Is there a good possibility with strtotime()?

Comment: You looking for something like this? $dateplusfive = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+5 days'));

Comment: yes but on a specific time.
I have found the below solution, perhaps not the best.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution, perhaps not the best.

````
$newdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+ 5 days 2 hours',strtotime('today midnight')));```
````

Comment: Why additional 2 hours though?

Comment: Also why don't you look at mktime(); function. That would give much finer control on getting the midnight timestamp.